# Active navbar item not staying active after click

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to 'Home', welcome_index_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Projects', projects_path %> </li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And this jquery to change the selected item based on a click, where `.selectednav` has `background-color: black`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("selectednav");
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("selectednav");

        });
    });
</script>
```

However, after clicking on a navbar item, the `.selectednav` class only applies to the element for a moment before disappearing.

The only way I have found to resolve this, is by removing the following line from the HTML:

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`

But this of course ruins my styling, and I would rather have this here to fit in with the rest of the bootstrap framework.

I have also tried with Bootstrap's built-in `active` class, but with the same result (removing the `ul` declaration fixes the issue but breaks my style).

Can anyone please tell me what is going on here, or what might be causing this?

It looks like because the page is redirecting to the link **after** changing the class, the `selectednav` class resets to whatever it was originally.

Comment: You should add the class active on page load, I suggest you to read this article, maybe it helps http://www.kevinleary.net/highlighting-the-current-page-with-php-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no problem with your.

```
$(this).addClass("selectednav");
$(this).siblings().removeClass("selectednav");
```

These are working fine with me.

There is another way of accomplishing this task. I have prepared a small fiddle.

Here's [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/sukhmeet032795/7sy265w2/8/). Here i am removing the current-item class from all li and then applying it to the current element.

You can take a look and then you will understand it better.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

i think this could help!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("nav li a").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("selectednav");
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("selectednav");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace this code just change the class from "selectednav" to "active":

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("li").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```